# Can Magneto control Colossus?

Tags: marvel, x-men, powers, magneto, colossus

I know Magneto can control magnetic fields, [to an insane extent](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3998/is-magnetos-power-magnetism-or-can-he-manipulate-all-metals), even to the point of manipulating Adamantium. I know he never does it in the movies, but is it ever explored in the comics or cartoons whether Magneto can control the metal that Colossus shifts into?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes, Magneto has demonstrated he can affect the organic analog of Osmium that Colossus can transform himself into. While Osmium is [normally not easily ferromagnetic](https://twin-cities.umn.edu/news-events/scientists-discover-new-magnetic-element) it is considered [paramagnetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paramagnetism), which means under a sufficiently powerful magnetic field, it can develop magnetic properties. Magneto's powers and ability to generate intense magnetic fields is a vulnerability to a person who turns into a material which can become MORE magnetic when exposed to such fields.

How much control is a matter of debate, but Magneto has shown he can affect Colossus, at least in simple ways. Magneto is able to hold Colossus at bay, freeze him in place or simply repel him great distances with apparently little effort, as he is seen doing in X-Men Vol 1, #112.

[image]

In X-Men Vol 1, #113, the X-Men confront Magneto again and Colossus reminds the readers that Magneto had used Colossus' metallic body against them (in the previous issue, no less). He reasons, as long as he keeps Magneto from concentrating by hammering him with his superhuman strength, Magneto won't be able to grab him with his power. Given the difference in their physical capabilities, it Magneto lets us know he needs to use all of his concentration to maintain his shields and thus could not take control of Peter's metallic form.

[image]

When Colossus takes on his metallic form, his mutant power transforms him into a being composed of an "organic osmium alloy", a super-dense metal with non-magnetic properties. [Osmium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osmium) is twice as dense as lead and nearly as hard as diamond. While the nature of the "organic osmium alloy" is a subject for debate, it is clear that Magneto's ability to control magnetism and to manipulate metals that are normally non-magnetic would not be challenged by Colossus' metallic form. Over the history of the two characters, Colossus' osmium form has proven to be a liability against Magneto in direct confrontations.

[image]

Recently, Colossus has become the Avatar of Cyttorak and is now the Unstoppable Juggernaut. With this transformation his power levels have been expanded significantly. Whether this will change the equation between him and Magneto is certain to be explored in coming issues.

Comment: Nice distinction regarding *control* as well pointing out the as yet explored question of whether recent changes will impact Magneto's influence.

Comment: This answer is long on bold statements, but utterly missing any actual evidence to back them up

Comment: Osmium is not even close to diamond's hardness.

Comment: Osmium is a hard but brittle metal that remains lustrous even at high temperatures. It has a very low compressibility. Correspondingly, its bulk modulus is extremely high, reported between 395 and 462 GPa, which rivals that of diamond (443 GPa). 

The hardness of osmium is moderately high at 4 GPa. Because of its hardness, brittleness, low vapor pressure (the lowest of the platinum-group metals), and very high melting point (the fourth highest of all elements, after carbon, tungsten, and rhenium), solid osmium is difficult to machine, form, or work.

Answer (score 28):

Magneto can manipulate Colossus. It's a semi-frequent theme between the two of them (like with Wolverine). Unsurprisingly, Magneto often comes on top where Colossus is concerned.

One example - X-Men #112:

[image: X-Men #112 cover]

A pertinent excerpt:
[image: Excerpt of X-Men #112 where Magneto vs Colossus]

*Neither one of these are my images or scans.*

Comment: I appreciate the actual images, so +1 for that, but I have to give it to @ThaddeusHowze. His post had more useful information in it. Thanks though. :)

Comment: Magneto knows Beast's one weakness: bad hair days