# Does Colossus' metal "disappear" when in normal form?

Tags: marvel, x-men, powers, colossus

Colossus has two main states:

- Normal (human) form
- Armored form

When in his normal form, is his metal completely gone, or is it somehow still in his molecular structure and just in a weaker state?
i.e. [can Magneto still control him](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/13103/27962) when he's in his normal form, or only in his armored form?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As [Marvel's own site explains](http://is.gd/create.php), the metal doesn't "*go*" anywhere - his organic tissue is literally *transformed* into a steel-like substance.

> **Colossus can transform his body tissue into an organic, steel-like substance** that grants him superhuman strength enabling him to lift/press up to 75 tons and makes him impervious to most injury. His armored form can withstand ballistic penetration as well as temperature extremes from 70º above absolute zero (-390º F) to approximately 9000º F. Colossus cannot become partially or selectively armored; his body is either entirely converted, or not at all.

In his armored form, he is [vulnerable to Magneto](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/13103/can-magneto-control-colossus), but in his non-armored form, his skin and body composition are the same as any normal human, and has no specific weakness to Magneto*.

<sup>*In later stories, Magneto is able to affect things by manipulating the electromagnetic fields around them. He could theoretically manipulate a non-armored Colossus like this, but this has nothing to do with Colossus' powers or abilities</sup>